# Preserve characters

Tags: python, json, csv, encoding

I have a JSON file which has been generated with python, it contains characters like:

```
\u2764\ufe0f\ud83d\udc9e\u2764\ufe0f\ud83d\udc9e
```

in a single string, just like that. Now that I am importing these into python again with the option:

```
encoding="utf-8"
```

and processing it to csv, again writing the with `encoding="utf-8"`. As soon as I take a look into the file, I see those characters changed to gibberish like

```
•ðŸŽ–
```

so now, this data is send to a MYSQL-DB. Viewing this later in HTML just makes no sense, some symbols get a question mark either appended or prepended. Looks like some essential information is lost there and only some is passed.

How would I correctly go about this? Is there any lib I could import to convert all of them to html like encoding?

Comment: Are you sure `.encode('utf-8')` doesn't work for you?

Comment: nope.... not at all but its default anyways and I would really like to find a way out of it... i am lacking deeper knowledge when it comes to this topic...

Comment: Interesting, I thought that html uses utf-8

Comment: How are you "taking a look into the file"?

Comment: currently I managed to insert values into the MYSQLDB, hence phpmyadmin and all values end up as questionmarks